# Can't show recieved data from API in Vuejs3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am new with Composition API 3 and trying to call an API and show data in page

My code is like this:

```
let items: IChannel[] = reactive([]);
async function get() {
  try {
    const res = await channelService.get()
    console.log(res)
    items = res.data;
  } catch (err) {
   console.log(err)
    Swal.fire("error", "error", "error");
  }
}
```

and it successfully gets data from API but *doesn't* show in  template:

```html
<template>
  {{ items }}
</template>
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting `items` (a `reactive` instance) with the raw data, which removes its reactivity:

```js
let items: IChannel[] = reactive([]);
⋮
items = res.data; ❌ overwrites `reactive`
```

### Option 1: Use object in `reactive`

Use a `reactive` *object* that receives the raw data:

```js
                           
const items = reactive({ items: [] as IChannel[] });
async function get() {
  try {
    const res = await channelService.get()
            
    items.items = res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    //...
  }
}
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-update-reactive-value?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

### Option 2: Use a `ref`

Use a `ref` instead of `reactive`, making sure to set its `value` property with the newly received raw data:

```js
               
const items = ref([] as IChannel[])
async function get() {
  try {
    const res = await channelService.get()
            
    items.value = res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    //...
  }
}
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-update-ref-value?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)